# Yii2 Как вывести логи из консольного приложения в web?

Tags: php, консоль, yii2, логирование

Есть *yii2 Basic*.
Часть Конфига `web.php`:

```
'bootstrap' => ['log'],
'components' => [

        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'flushInterval' => 1,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning','info'],
                    'exportInterval' => 1,
                ],
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['info'],
                    'exportInterval' => 1,
                    'logVars' => [/*'_GET', '_POST', '_FILES', '_COOKIE', '_SESSION'*/],
                    'categories' => ['pixels'],
                    'logFile' => '@app/runtime/logs/pixels.log',
                    'maxFileSize' => 1024 * 2,
                    'maxLogFiles' => 20,
                ],
            ],
        ],

    ],
```

Часть конфига `console.php`:

```
'bootstrap' => ['log', 'gii'],
'controllerNamespace' => 'app\commands',
'components' => [
    'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
    ],
    'log' => [
        'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
        'flushInterval' => 1,
        'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning','info'],
                'exportInterval' => 1,
            ],
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['info'],
                'exportInterval' => 1,
                'logVars' => [/*'_GET', '_POST', '_FILES', '_COOKIE', '_SESSION'*/],
                'categories' => ['pixels'],
                'logFile' => '@app/runtime/logs/pixels.log',
                'maxFileSize' => 1024 * 2,
                'maxLogFiles' => 20,
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

В контроллере консоли выводил логи разными способами:

```
Yii::info('text', 'pixels');
```

и так

```
Yii::getLogger()->log('text', Logger::LEVEL_INFO, 'pixels');
```

Не записывает в логи.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как записать логи из консольного приложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не могу знать в чем у вас проблема, но поделюсь рабочим кодом:

console.php

```
    <?php

Yii::setAlias('@tests', dirname(__DIR__) . '/tests');

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');
$db = require(__DIR__ . '/db.php');

return [
    'id' => 'basic-console',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log', 'gii'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'app\commands',
    'modules' => [
        'gii' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    ],
    'components' => [
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'log' => [
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning','info'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => $db,
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

@app/commands/TestController.php

```
<?php

namespace app\commands;

use Yii;
use yii\console\Controller;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
    $string = 'This is a testing string';   
    Yii::info($string);
        echo 'console Works!'."\n";
    }
}
```

После запуска команды `php yii test/index` в лог (@app/runtime/logs/app.log) падает следующая информация

> 2015-08-02 06:58:15 [-][-][-][info][application] This is a testing
>   string